# Vector iterator passed to function error

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, point-cloud-library

I would like to pass a point cloud as an input argument to a function proposed by the point cloud library, but here's my problem:
I have a vector of point cloud, and I want to pass them one by one to a filter to eventually put them into another vector of point cloud filtered. I am using an iterator for that, but the function expecting a point cloud as an input does not take the iterator... I don't understand why. The code:

```
std::vector <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr> pcl_filter(std::vector <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr> rdy_to_pro_pcls){
    std::vector<int> indices;
    std::vector <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr>::iterator vIt_pcls = rdy_to_pro_pcls.begin();
    std::vector <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr> vFilt_pcls;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr without_nanpcl(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr filt_pcl(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

    for (vIt_pcls = rdy_to_pro_pcls.begin(); vIt_pcls != rdy_to_pro_pcls.end(); vIt_pcls++){

        pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(*vIt_pcls, *without_nanpcl, indices);
        pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGB> sor;
        sor.setInputCloud(*vIt_pcls);
        sor.setLeafSize(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
        sor.filter(*filt_pcl);
        vFilt_pcls.push_back(filt_pcl);
    }
    return vFilt_pcls;
}
```

I actually want to to put the without_nanpcl object into a vector. I can't go further since my debugger doesn't approve what I'm doing. As you can see below there is a function called setInputCloud which accepts the vector iterator, and I want to do the exact same thing with pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud, but I can't figure out why it is not working.

Here is the error output (line 8 of the sample of code):

```
error C2784: 'void pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(const pcl::PointCloud<PointT> &,pcl::PointCloud<PointT> &,std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const pcl::PointCloud<PointT> &' from 'boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>>'
```

And here is the pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud declaration:

```
void pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud   (
const pcl::PointCloud< PointT > &   cloud_in,
pcl::PointCloud< PointT > &     cloud_out,
std::vector< int > &    index 
)
```

Could you help me on this?
thank you

Comment: 1. *Debugger* doesn't approve? What does that mean? Are you perhaps getting a compilation error? If so, post the complete error message and the line on which it occurs. 2. Please show the declaration of `pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud`

Comment: Sorry for the display of my answer, Im not sure of how to underline the code...

Comment: Edit your question and add the error message and indicate which source line it is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks I've just done it

Comment: Error messages have line numbers in them. Do not omit those. Make sure the offending line is posted, marked with **this is line number 12345** comment, and enough source lines above it are included in the post to provide context.

Comment: thank you for your advices, I will keep it in mind for my next questions

Comment: removeNaNFromPointCloud expects a "const pcl::PointCloud< PointT > & cloud_in" but you are passing a "pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr". This is not the same. So what's in there you do not understand? BTW, how are PointT and pcl::PointXYZRGB related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the function signature, you can see that it expects a reference to `pcl::PointCloud< PointT >` (I assume it's actually a function template and `PointT` is its template parameter), but you're passing in a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr`, obtained by dereferencing the iterator. You need to dereference the pointer as well to get at the point cloud object:

```
pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(**vIt_pcls, *without_nanpcl, indices);
```